# MVC4 Checkbox is always false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

my form looks like

```
..
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(s => s.Invoices, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "data-mini", "true" } })
...
```

and my model:

```
public class SalesSelectMobileViewModel
{
    public bool Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

after submitting the form I see two values (true,false) - actual Checkbox and Hidden input and I am well aware why both of them are sent, but parsed value is always false. Am I missing some binder in the configuration? Its a rather large project that I'm working on and I'm having a hard time isolating the problem.

Comment: If both values are being sent then the only reason why the property would be false is that the value isn't being bound. For that, we need to see your model, your controller action signature and - ideally - the POST body.

Comment: @AntP Relevant data here: http://pastebin.com/FvcTLDz0

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out.

I was using jQuery Mobile classes and structure - but I was using them incorrectly and jQuery Mobile Javascript post processing messed up the order of elements so that form submitted values in this order:

```
Invoices=false&Invoices=true
```

and this is not parsed correctly!
it should be like this, because first parameter is parsed

```
Invoices=true&Invoices=false
```